# Problema con XAMPP/archivo dll

Tags: sql-server, apache, xampp

tengo instalado en mi computador el XAMPP y hace un tiempo tuve que trabajar con SQL Server, investigue en Google para poder agregar las extensiones de SQL Server para trabajarlo junto a PHP y lo instale todo bien hasta ahí.

Ahora tuve que trabajar con otro computador diferente al mio, le instale el XAMPP y todo funcionaba bien pero cuando tuve que instalar las extensiones de SQL Server me comenzó a salir un error al momento de iniciar el Apache.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el error me sale unas 4 veces presionando "aceptar" y el Apache se inicia normal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad no encontré nada investigando acerca del error o algo relacionado, aunque el Apache se inicia me da miedo que pueda fallar algo mientras programo.

Debo preocuparme por este error?

Como puedo solucionarlo?

Adjunto los archivos dll(extensiones) de SQL Server y como los instale por si encuentran alguna anomalía porque como dije arriba el error no me salia hasta después de agregarlas.

Estos son los archivos ya instalados en la carpeta `php/ext`[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente este es el archivo `PHP.ini` donde debía especificar las extensiones para que comenzaran a usar el SQL Server junto al PHP

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que versión de php tienes? por el diseño de control panel me párese que fuera 5 y no 7

Comment: Cuando abro el phpinfo() me sale: PHP Version 7.2.9

Comment: En el equipo antes había instalado una versión menor de php? Probaste reinstalando xampp?

Comment: No, es la primera ves que se instala xampp en el equipo y si probé reinstalando

Comment: Si `Thread Safety` es enable en `phpinfo` usa los dll `ts` de lo contrario los `nts`

Comment: Esa fue! quite los nts de la carpeta y del php.ini y ya no sale el error, pero tengo una duda porque en mi pc no pasaba esto? si tengo instalados los ts y nts